# Match longest repeating sequence (that is not made of a repeating sequence)

Tags: regex

Consider the string

```
aabaabaabaabaab
```

Clearly this string is made of 5 adjacent occurences of `aab`, so I want my regex to match `aab`.

To elaborate: `aabaab` wouldn't be an acceptable output because it's made by repeating `aab`. But `aab` is a valid result because it's not made of a repeated shorter string.

For the sake of the question, let us assume that there can be additional text around the repeated segment (for example `11aabaabaabaabaab22` or even `xaabaabaabaabaabaa`). Therefore it's not possible to anchor the regex with `^` or `$`.

---

Failed idea #1: `(.+?)\1+` This captures `aa` instead of the expected `aab`.

Failed idea #2: `(.+)\1+` This captures `aabaab`.

Is it possible to do this with pure regex? If yes, is it possible without dynamic-width lookbehind?

Comment: Note that if you add anchors you get the correct result: `^(.+)\1+$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good point. But let us assume that there can be more data at the beginning or end of the string. I'll update the question.

Comment: you could do this recursively, doing `(.+)\1+` the first time, and then doing `^(.+?)\1+$` every subsequent time till you don't get a match, when you don't get a match then the last value tried is the one you want

Comment: Sounds difficult. This string is also made of 2 adjacent occurences of `aabaab`.

Comment: If we can do a lookahead, `(.+)(?=\1)` multiple times in the way described by @MichaelGorman would work in the same way

Comment: yeah, its not an efficient answer, but the first iteration would find the biggest repeating pattern, and each subsequent iteration would determine if that can be split into a pattern

Comment: @KindStranger when I tried that I got 4 matches, `aabaab`, `aab`, `aab`, and `a` which does contain the correct answer, but would need to still be iterated over to see which one is correct

Comment: Wouldn't `aabaab` actually be the longest repeating sequence considering that it does have 6 characters (more than 3 from `aab`) and repeat again? `aabaab aabaab aab`. Meaning your "failed idea #2" would be correct.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes, `aabaab` would be longer, but the reason it's not an acceptable result is because it's made by repeating `aab`. But `aab` is a valid answer because it's not made of a repeated shorter string. Maybe I should make the question more clear.

Comment: Gotcha, I now see that in the title, but the question didn't explain it. I can't think of a way to do it without getting all repeating sequences and looping to check afterwards which was the longest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use two lookaheads, the first one searches the longest pattern and the second searches the smallest. The second pattern repeated has to end (at least) at the same position or after the first pattern repeated. To check that, you have to capture the end of the string in the first lookahead and to use a backreference to this capture in the second lookahead.

```
(?=(.+)\1+(.*))(?=(.+?)\3+\2$)\3+
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBCTyN/2)

The result is in the group 3

also:

```
(?=(.+)\1+(.*))(.+?)\3+(?=\2$)\3*
```

---

Note that these two regex patterns give the result for one position in a string. If you want to know what is the shortest pattern that is the longest substring once repeated for all the string, you have to find all of them and to select the longest susbstring with code. You can use a pattern for overlapping results to do that:

```
(?=(.+)\1+(.*))(?=(.+?)\3+\2$)(?=(\3+))
```

*(using the group 4)*

Comment: Using that additional `(.*)` group to make sure both matches end at the same location is genius. +1 and much respect!

Answer (score 1):

```
def largest_pattern(value)
  /(.+)\1+/.match(value).try("[]", 1)
end

def smallest_pattern(value)
  /^(.+?)\1+$/.match(value).try("[]", 1)
end

def largest_distinct_pattern(value)
  val = largest_pattern(value)
  if val
    while(new_val = smallest_pattern(val))
      val = new_val
    end
    val
  else
    nil
  end
end

largest_distinct_pattern("aabaabaabaabaab")
=> "aab"
```

Comment: This will fail if there were more than one repeating sequence where the largest repeating pattern was not the largest sequence. For example `abcabc1212121212`. The largest pattern of repeating sequence is `12`  but the `abc` is longer for smallest pattern.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm looking for a no code, pure regex solution.

Comment: Yeah, Casimir et Hippolyte's answer is a much cleaner solution anyways.

Comment: @MichaelGorman: Thanks but I really don't believe that my solution is clean or efficient. For me this kind of question is more like a programming puzzle. *(do that thing that seems impossible with a regex)*